# New Laptop Blues (Visual Studio 2008)

Tags: windows-xp, laptop, performance, hp-elitebook

I've read the best laptop for VS2008 threads but I think there may be more to my situation, I hope someone can shed some light.

My company just got me the following:

HP Elitebook
2.5 ghz pentium III
3 gig ram
SATA 7200 drive
XP 32 SP3

Out of the box it has the following items in the start bar:
McAfee Virus Scan Enterprise 8.7
Cisco Clean Access Agent
Drive Encryption-Inactive

Synaptics mobile pointint device
intel graphics accelorator
something taking the place of the standard wireless networks (although I'm normally connected via Cat5)

standard install on VS2008, SQL 2008

On the surface I wouldn't expect this machine to be really slow but it is.  if I open windows explorer I get between 18 and 25 SECONDS before items will display and control will fully return.  this also occurs while browsing the tree.

I see weird pauses just doing Email, failed screen redraws and don't even get me started about using VS2008 which has all the file switching or Sql2008

I set up my tools on an imac (1.83 ghz) and parallels and it runs better than any laptop they've given me (this is the 3rd) in VIRTUALIZATION!

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Was the "pentium III" in the question a mistype, or is it real?

Answer (score 0):

The Intel Chipset Driver could be what's missing.

These files indicate to the operating system how the chipset components are to be configured, and as far as I know Windowx XP lacks support for the chipset out-of-the-box. And without them the computer will work much slower the usual.

You haven't written which model you're using, but it should be pretty easy to find the right driver on HP's site.

Answer (score 0):

I went to HP and installed the latest for my EliteBook 6930 It seems to be about 5 seconds faster but still at 11 to 17 seconds for starting windows explorer

Answer (score 0):

HP writes their own graphics drivers.  I've personally had a lot of experience with this model laptop as it's what we use at work.  I think the graphics drivers are not working correctly.  My boss has an 8530p laptop with an ATI graphics card.  He has the same problems with Windows explorer not working as it should.  The screen takes a lot longer than it should to redraw itself.  The best stable solution I've found is to change the transition effect (Right click desktop, Properties, Appearance, Effects) to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to disable all antivirus etc. and especially McAfee ...
You can very easily find out if it's an application that's slowing you, by doing a safe reboot and seeing if the performance then is normal. VS2008 will work in safe mode and is a good test program.
If safe-boot solves your problem, then just disable the applications one by one until you find the guilty one. If not, then the fun starts : it's either a problem with the Windows setup (a driver or whatever) or even hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Go back to the IT department and describe the problem, it sounds like you've got a duff laptop. If the company expect you to develop on it, it needs to be up to scratch.

Comment: Sounds that way.  Could be a faulty hard drive too - if it's not spinning properly, you'll get slowdowns.  Plus the startup is quite heavy.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install VS 2008 Service Pack 1? I've found it necessary to make the application usable.